# How to make a relation between two tables in PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables users and articles and I have the id for each table (auto_increment). How to make a relation between the user (Who written this article) and the article to give permissions to delete and edit.

Comment: Either create a 3rd table called `user_article` that has a composite primary key of the `user` and `article` table's PKs OR just add a column on the article called `created_by` and populate it with the user's PK

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using a mapping table that maps between article.id to it's owner user.id
Based on page load you can validate if the user has edit access to the article
this is a one to many relationship where the one is the user and many are the articles.

```
+------------+------------+---------------+--+--+
| mapping_id | article_id | owner_user_id |  |  |
+------------+------------+---------------+--+--+
| 1          | 123        | 456           |  |  |
+------------+------------+---------------+--+--+
| 2          |            |               |  |  |
+------------+------------+---------------+--+--+
| 3          |            |               |  |  |
+------------+------------+---------------+--+--+
```